# Cursor moves off down in mobile site - Weird issue probably cz of apple keyboard

Tags: css, html, responsive-design, cursor-position

I am facing this weird issue which I think is because of apple keyboard. When I tap on the input field, the keyboard comes from the bottom and the cursor moves off down like this:

[image]

And when I scroll up with the modal open, it comes back to place like this:

[image]

What could be probable issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue in iOS 11 which happens when an `<input>` element is inside a `position:fixed` container and is thoroughly described in [this blogpost](https://hackernoon.com/how-to-fix-the-ios-11-input-element-in-fixed-modals-bug-aaf66c7ba3f8).

The workarounds are for now:

1. Making the modal window `position: absolute` instead of `fixed`
2. Hiding the content behind the modal with `display:none` and stretching the modal to cover the whole page
3. Avoiding modals altogether

None of the workarounds is particularly a 100% solution, but none of the iOS 11 updates have yet fixed the issue.